# how to get my Azure Synapse database and table not to always be lower cased

Tags: azure-data-lake, azure-synapse

I'm running the following in my Synapse pyspark notebook to create a database and table:

```
%%sql
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS Database1 LOCATION '/Database1';
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Database1.Table1(Column1 int) USING CSV OPTIONS (header=true);
```

Then I see 'database1' and 'table1' in the studio ui. BTW, I see 'Database1/table1' as the folder names in ADLS.

Is there a way to preserve the case for both of these?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

running this seems to do the trick: spark.conf.set('spark.sql.caseSensitive', True)

Comment: where/how did you run this?